# How to bind list<string> to a viewlist in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `List<String>` and I want to bind it to a `ListView` dynamically  Could you please tell me how to do it?

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="item: "></asp:Label> 
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("model") %>'></asp:Label>      
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:ListView> 
</td>
```

this is the object class which i store in Session

```
public class ShoppingCart
{

    List<string> cartContent;

    public ShoppingCart()
    {
        cartContent = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> Cart
    {
        get
        {
            return cartContent;
        }
    }
```

and here i insert items

```
((ShoppingCart)Session["cart"]).Cart.Add(lbtnModel.Text);
```

and here i ma binding

```
           List<string> ItemsList = ((ShoppingCart)Session["cart"]).Cart;
        ListView1.DataSource = ItemsList;
        ListView1.DataBind();
```

I want to set `Label2.text` dynamically

Comment: `Listview1.DataSource = yourList; Listview1.DataBind()`?!

Comment: Use this instead in your aspx: `<%# Container.DataItem %>` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ***rough*** example:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("Foo");

myListView.DataSource = myList;
myListView.DataBind();
```

You can change the `DataSource` anytime you wish.  You will just need to remember to `DataBind()` it.

Comment: <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="item: "></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("model") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </td>  i want to set Label2.text dynamically

Comment: @Sum If you want to show more code, use the "edit" button at the bottom of your original post.  That way you can format it more clearly than it is in your comment =)

Comment: @Sum I think you got it covered so long as "model" exists as a property of the data item in your list collection.

Comment: i tried many way, but it does not work, i do not know how to link the lable2.text with the list<string> values???

Comment: @Sum please provide code used to populate your list.  We'll have to understand what kind of data you are working with.  Not sure if you are working with a collection of strings, or a collection of custom objects.  It makes a difference.